# Capitalizing first char in every word in a String in java (but ignoring specific word)

Tags: java, string

Can anyone please tell me why the following code prints 1 the high street and not 1 The High Street?:

```
    String propertyPageTitle = "1-the-high-street";
    propertyPageTitle = propertyPageTitle.replace("-", " ");
    WordUtils.capitalizeFully(propertyPageTitle);
    System.out.println(propertyPageTitle);
```

EDIT to show solution:

```
    String propertyPageTitle = "1-the-high-street";
    propertyPageTitle = propertyPageTitle.replace("-", " ");
    propertyPageTitle = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(propertyPageTitle);
    System.out.println(propertyPageTitle);
```

Supposing I wanted to ignore the word 'and' if it appears (I'm reading values from a .csv) and NOT change to titlecase?  how would that be possible.

Answer (score 1):

WordUtils.capitalizeFully does not change the original String, but instead *returns* the capitalized String.

```
propertyPageTitle = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(propertyPageTitle);
```

Comment: really, I want to capitalize fully (first letter of each String) UNLESS the word is 'and'.  So I suppose I can build some logic around capitalizeFully to handle this scenario

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `capitalizeFully(String)` of `WordUtils` returns a `String` which has the expected answer. So try:

```
propertyPageTitle = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(propertyPageTitle);
```

And then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
String firstStr = "i am fine";
String capitalizedStr = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(firstStr);
System.out.println(capitalizedStr);
```

The return should be taken to get the output of a method. It is common for all methods in Java String

Answer (score 0):

```
    String toBeCapped = "1 the high street and 2 low street";

    String[] tokens = toBeCapped.split("\\s");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (!tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("and")) {
            char capLetter = Character.toUpperCase(tokens[i].charAt(0));
            builder.append(" ");
            builder.append(capLetter);
            builder.append(tokens[i].substring(1, tokens[i].length()));
        } else {
            builder.append(" and");
        }
    }
    toBeCapped = builder.toString().trim();
    System.out.println(toBeCapped);
```

output:

```
1 The High Street and 2 Low Street
```